# Foreach condition to add a number instead of get duplicate a item in laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement, foreach, duplicates, conditional-statements

first of all, thanks for your time and your example, im trying to be like you guys, to help more people. I am new at laravel and i need to solve a problem, with this foreach im trying to make a stats view (see the .jpg) and i have duplicated items, this is my code...

```
@foreach ($statsnation as $item)

    @foreach ($naciones as $key => $nacion)
        @if ($item->nationality == $nacion->nacion_id )
            <div class="row col-4 border ">
                <div class="text-dark  col-8 p-3">{{ $nacion->GENTILICIO_NAC }} </div>
                <div class="col-2 borderless p-3">{{count($item)}}</div>
                <div class="col-2 borderless p-3">{{ number_format(count($nacion)*100/$activos) }}%</div>
            </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

this is the result with the for each, i have duplicate items and i need to add it instead:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are not passing the foreach loop duplicated data?

Comment: yes im passing the duplicated data, but i dont know to make that does not happen. Or where to read..

Comment: Remove the index from the $statsnation array or use unset (See php docs on how to remove from array or how to use unset() function )

Comment: even if im using laravel? the index is $statsnation  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is :

```
        @foreach ($regiones as $key => $region)
        @if(count($statsnation->where('region', $region->region_id )) == 0)
        @else
                <div class="row col-4 border ">
                    <div class="text-dark  col-8 p-3">{{ $region->region_ordinal }} {{ $region->region_nombre }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 borderless p-3">{{count($statsnation->where('region', $region->region_id ))}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 borderless p-3">{{count($statsnation->where('region', $region->region_id ))*100/count($statsnation)}}%                   </div>
                </div>


        @endif
        @endforeach
```

in this case i use regions instead of nations, its just replacing $vars but now my app avoid duplicity and avoids division by 0 by not showing regions that dont have records.

sorry about my code, its a mess, im just learning and i need to use good practices